# Andoroid screenshot with delay timer

Tags: gratis, android, screenshot

I am looking for a gratis Android app.

Minimal functionality:

- must be able to delay the screen shot (still image) by X seconds where X is preferably user-defined
- initiated by an icon, ***NOT*** by a combination of physical keys, such as <kbd>volume down</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd>.

That's it, all else, such as captioning, video capture, etc, is a bonus.

Comment: You should urgently work on your finger coordination (or at least proof-read your text before posting it ;) Solutions requiring root acceptable? And triggering via notification area, instead of an icon on your home screen? Not that I have a solution in mind, but those details help focus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several candidates meeting your requirements:

#### [Screenshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splendapps.splendshot)

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splendapps.splendshot); click images for larger variants)</sup>

This seems to be a very suitable candidate. Not only matches your described requirements, but allows for multiple additional ways to be triggered: hotkeys and notification area included. Also included is a nice gallery of the screenshots you've already done (see above), plus the capability of editing/cropping screenshots and uploading them to different sites.

- **Delay:** Yes (see first screenshot; of course neither countdown nor the floating icon are captured)
- **initiated by an icon:** Yes, but also several different options
- **Gratis:** Yes.
- **root required:** No, but might be needed for some functions (not sure which).
- **Up-to-dateness:** Last release 2 month ago.

#### [screenshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geeksoft.screenshot)

Same name, but note the "lowercase <kbd>s</kbd>".

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>screenshot (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geeksoft.screenshot); click images for larger variants)</sup>

- **Delay:** Yes (see last screenshot)
- **initiated by an icon:** Yes, but also several different options (e.g. "shake")
- **Gratis:** Yes.
- **root required:** No, but might be needed for some functions (not sure which).
- **Up-to-dateness:** Last release a year ago.

#### [Touchshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbs.util.takescreen)

As pointed out by the OP, there's also *Touchshot* with which Mawg finally ended up:

[image: Touchshot] [image: Touchshot] [image: Touchshot]
<sup>*Touchshot* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbs.util.takescreen); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Though missing from the app's description, OP confirms it meets all the requirements – so I omit those details here. It's well rated (more than 4 stars at 300+ votes) and (at the point of this writing) very much up-to-date.

---

There are several other candidates out there. But those I know of are either completely outdated (not updated for much more than one year – so it's not clear if they'd still work on recent Android versions), or not available for free. Hope one of these two comes up to your expectations :)

Comment: Both of these work well, thanks. In the end, though, I prefer https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbs.util.takescreen&hl=en which plaecs a samll, floating toolbar on the screen, and hands both stills and movies.

Comment: @Mawg does it fit all requirements, including the dealy? If so, shall I integrate it with my answer (to make it easier to spot for other readers) – or do you prefer writing you own answer?

Comment: Yes, it has a timer. Feel free to integrate it woth your answer (thanks for doing the work ;-)